# DocuSign collector service calls supporting multi-threads call for batch process

Tags: multithreading, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is Collector service calls in DocuSign supporting multi-threads call???

We are expecting to have a high volume Collector Service Calls to process the DocuSign Batch Process and moving to our Content Management Storage.

Would like to ensure that the DocuSign Collector Service Calls are supporting Multi-Threading.

Comment: what is the DocuSign Collector service? do you mean Connect?

Comment: Yes, connector.

Comment: well, still not sure you mean what we mean, but if that's the case - then yes, it does

Comment: To clarify :
Is Connector Service Calls in DocuSign supporting Multi-Thread Call?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you point me to something that tells me what are you talking about?